# Qt: Interesting bug occurred convert QString to float

Tags: c++, qt

I found a interesting thing when i try to converting QString to float by using toFloat() function.

Here is the code:

```
QString src = "500.05";
int x = src.toFloat() * 100;
float y = src.toFloat() * 100;
int z = (int)(500.05 * 100);

qDebug() << x;
qDebug() << y;
qDebug() << z;
```

And here is the output:

```
50004 //x
50005 //y
50005 //z
```

My question is why i got `x` is `50004`.
So is this a Bug or i did something incorrect.

Comment: You have a *round up error*: `500.05 * 100` is actually something like `50004.999999999`

Comment: Thanks, So is this consider as a Bug of Qt?
Or i suppose use other way to convert QString to float?

Comment: that´s *expected behaviour*. Probably you want to *round up* to the *nearest integer*: `(int)(500.05 * 100 + 0.5);` note `+0.5`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) explains the issues with floating points.